# What is the meaning of this pinescript statement?

Tags: pine-script

When pinescript does only:

`var col = 1`

`col := col == -1 and VarA > VarB ? 1 : col == 1 and VarA < VarB ? -1 : col`

how is "col == -1" ever true since the initialization was 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert any [ternary](https://converter.website-dev.eu/) (`?:`) construction to an `if-then-else` on [this website](https://converter.website-dev.eu/)

Your example

```
col == -1 and VarA > VarB ? 1 : col == 1 and VarA < VarB ? -1 : col
```

Yields this

```
if (col == -1 and VarA > VarB) {
    1
} else {
    if (col == 1 and VarA < VarB) {
        -1
    } else {
        col
    }
}
```

Assuming you meant `var col = 1` instead of `var dir = 1` in your question,
the only way that `col` would get a `-1` value, is when `VarA < VarB`.

**Breakdown**

***On first bar***

```
var col = 1
```

This initializes `col` to value `1`.
This initialization does not repeat on every bar.
This initialization is only done once, because of the `var` keyword.

Excerpt from the manual on [Variable declaration](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html#variable-declaration):
*The var keyword is a special modifier that instructs the compiler to create and initialize the variable only once.
This behavior is very useful in cases where a variable’s value must persist through the iterations of a script across successive bars.*

```
if (col == -1 and VarA > VarB)
```

First part of the `and` statement yields `false`, because `col` is `1`.
So, the entire `and` statement yields `false`.
Code continues to the first `else`.

```
if (col == 1 and VarA < VarB)
```

First part of the `and` statement yields `true`, because `col` is `1`.
Depending on wether `VarA < VarB` is `true` or `false`, `col` gets assigned `-1` or it's own current `col` value.
For arguments sake, let's say `VarA < VarB` yields `true`.
Then, the entire `and` statement yields `true`, making the `if` statement `true`.
The value `-1` gets assigned to `col`.

***On second bar***

`col` now has value `-1`.

```
if (col == -1 and VarA > VarB)
```

First part of the `and` statement yields `true`, because `col` is `-1`.
If `VarA > VarB` is `true`, `col` gets assigned `1`.
The entire statement is done here.

If `VarA > VarB` is `false`, code continues to the first `else`.

```
if (col == 1 and VarA < VarB)
```

First part of the `and` statement yields `false`, because `col` is `-1`.
So, the entire `and` statement yields `false`.
The current value of `col` gets assigned to `col`.
So the `col` variable remains at `-1`.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I did mean col = 1 (it was a typo). What I don't get is how would the first statement ever  be true since it seems to iterate.

Comment: The [Pine execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html) is very different from classic programming languages. Your script is executed on every bar. It's not clear to me what you don't understand. It's a simple if-then-else.

Comment: I get it, but col is initialized to 1. If it iterates through every bar how could it ever be -1 on the first check of a bar?

Comment: Wait, are you saying col here is just a singular (global) variable and not a column? If true that might simplify things.

Comment: Indeed, `col` is just a variable. The `var` keyword means it's only initialized once, at the first bar, and keeps it's state throughout subsequent bars, unless changed by a `col :=` statement. Not sure why you think `col` is a column.

Comment: I thought that because the initial code was col = 1 <newline> col := nz(col[1], col), and I read that in newer versions it can be replaced with 'var col = 1' only, and I did and the final outcome of the program is the same.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a breakdown of how it's processed on the first 2 bars.